# How does setState work in this example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm reading over the [React Native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html) and I'm fairly confused about the `TextInput` section:

```
<TextInput
    style={{height: 40}} 
    placeholder="Type here to translate!"
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
/>
```

**What I understand:**

I realize that `onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({text: txt})}` works and that makes sense to me, since the parameter is being applied to the state `text`

---

**What I don't understand:**

I don't understand how `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}` works. Why does the parameter `text` have to be named the same as the state `text`? I understand that it is equivalent to `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}`, but I don't understand why. If the parameter was just being passed to the state variable, then`onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({text})}` would work, but it doesn't.

I tried searching for an answer and asking multiple people, but I haven't received a clear explanation yet.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing [shorthand object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions), a feature new in ES2015. If the property and value are the same, then you don't need to provide the value:

```
const obj = {
  foo
};
```

Is the same as:

```
const obj = {
  foo: foo
};
```

So in this case, it is equivalent to (and desugars to):

```
(text) => this.setState({ text: text })
```

The reason why it doesn't work when you try:

```
(txt) => this.setState({ text })
```

Is because in the first example, `text`, the value of the property refers to the argument of the arrow function:

```
(text) => this.setState({ text: text })
//                              ^^^^ refers to the argument `text`
```

In the second snippet, `text` is the value, but there is no `text` variable because you changed the argument to `txt`, thus it does not work:

```
(txt) => this.setState({ text: text })
//                              ^^^^ refers to the argument `text` but it doesn't exist, it is called `txt`!
```

The value must be the same as the key.

Answer (score 0):

this.setstate() is a function. When you instantiate the state object in your Constructor `this.state = {foo: bar}` you are creating an object. So when you call this.setState() you are updating that object. So your example you could write it like this and have the same result:

```
onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({text: txt})}
```

To access this, you would use `this.state.text`

Answer (score 0):

This feature is [Property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) from ES2015 (ES6).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you have a hard time understanding is a new feature in es6 called `object literal property value shorthand`. 
https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand